# Relative velocity and pseudo forces

Tags: forces, relative-motion

If I am in a spaceship moving in deep space....... which is accelerating.... There is nothing around to compare my motion with.... How can I say even if I'm moving or not....if I say I experience a pseudo force on me which pushes me backwards.... Then can I say that I'm accelerating...?? Is this force a real one.... As it is not real force... Because others cannot experience pseudo forces from outside the system...." My main question is that...."can I say that my spaceship is accelerating by experiencing the pseudo force"